# Sort items using an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am wanting to sort a list of links to match an array order:

```
List: 

<a href="" data-value="10">10</a>
<a href="" data-value="6">6</a>
<a href="" data-value="8">8</a>
...
<a href="" data-value="m">M</a>
<a href="" data-value="s">S</a>

Array for Ordering:

['6', '8', '10', '12', '14', 'xs', 's', 'm', 'l', 'xl', 'xxl']
```

I am using the following which sorts the text options fine, but not the numerical ones:

```
(function () {
    var order = ['6', '8', '10', '12', '14', 'xs', 's', 'm', 'l', 'xl', 'xxl'];
    var $wrapper = $('.size-filter');
    $wrapper.find('a').sort(function (a, b) {
      var aSize = $(a).data('value'), bSize = $(b).data('value');
      return order.indexOf(aSize) - order.indexOf(bSize);
    }).appendTo($wrapper);
  })();
```

How can I adjust this sorting function or rewrite it so it sorts both text and numerical size options?

Comment: How should the sorted array look like?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there's only one link per `data-value` or can there be multiple? If the latter, what should determine the secondary sorting?

Comment: @Phil yes there is only ever one link per value

Comment: @Pedro cool, just making sure my answer wouldn't blow up your app 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the links in a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), keyed by their `data-value` attribute, then [*map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the `order` array to the links

```js
const links = [...document.querySelectorAll('a[data-value]')].reduce((map, link) =>
    map.set(link.dataset.value, link), new Map())

const orderedLinks = order.filter(k => links.has(k)).map(k => links.get(k))
```

You can then use jQuery to append these links to another element

```js
$('some-element-selector').append(orderedLinks)
```

Note that I've filtered the `order` array to one where links actually exist.

Comment: Works perfect, only change I made was to display the orderedLinks back in the page. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Pedro I just added that to my answer but from the code in your question, I figured you already knew how to do that